# SQL Script condition to fill a new column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables on a SQL Server database:

**C093** *(called employee)*
C093_COD (pk),
C093_TYPE *values: 0 (registered) or 1 (intern)*,
FPC026_COD (fk)
...

**FPC026** *(called syndicate)*
FPC026_COD (pk)
...

**FPC001** *(called institute)*
FPC001_COD (pk),
FPC026_COD (fk)
...

How it works: an employee can be an intern or registered. Every institue has an associated syndicate.
The FPC026_COD (fk) on C093 is a brand new column. The syndicate of the institute of the employee must be on this new columnn, except when this new field is already filled (keeps the same value) or the employee is an intern (must set to null).

For example: John is an employee of the Apple institute. This institute has an associated syndicate, called Apple Syndicate. I want associate John to Apple Syndicate by this new column on employee's table. If John were an intern, it should be null. If John were already associated to Apple Syndycate, this new field should remain as it is.

I tried something like this:

```
UPDATE C093
SET FPC026_COD =
  CASE 
    WHEN FPC026_COD IS NOT NULL THEN FPC026_COD
    WHEN C093_TYPE = 1 THEN NULL
    WHEN C093_TYPE = 0 THEN FPC001.FPC026_COD
  END;
COMMIT;
```

But I don't know how to get FPC001.FPC026_COD

Comment: Tag which DBMS you are using.

Comment: That's not what a tag is...

Comment: Aren't you just missing the FROM clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find this simplest to implement using subqueries:

```
UPDATE C093
    SET FPC026_COD = (CASE WHEN FPC026_COD IS NOT NULL
                           THEN FPC026_COD
                           WHEN C093_TYPE = 1
                           THEN NULL
                           WHEN C093_TYPE = 0
                           THEN (SELECT FPC001.FPC026_COD FROM FPC001 WHERE FPC001.?? = C093.??)
                      END);
COMMIT;
```

By the way, the first two conditions in the `CASE` can be combined:

```
UPDATE C093
    SET FPC026_COD = (CASE WHEN FPC026_COD IS NOT NULL OR C093_TYPE = 1
                           THEN FPC026_COD
                           WHEN C093_TYPE = 0
                           THEN (SELECT FPC001.FPC026_COD FROM FPC001 WHERE FPC001.?? = C093.??)
                      END);
```

The `??` is because the `JOIN` keys are unclear.  Use the appropriate `JOIN` keys.

You can also do this with a `JOIN`, but it needs to be an outer join:

```
UPDATE C093
    SET FPC026_COD = (CASE WHEN FPC026_COD IS NOT NULL OR C093_TYPE = 1
                           THEN FPC026_COD
                           WHEN C093_TYPE = 0
                           THEN FPC001.FPC026_COD 
                      END)
    FROM C093 LEFT JOIN
         FPC001 
         ON FPC001.?? = C093.??;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must join two tables.
Something likes this.

```
UPDATE Table_a
SET Table_a.FPC026_COD=Table_b.Col1
FROM (
SELECT CASE 
WHEN C093 .FPC026_COD IS NOT NULL THEN C093 .FPC026_COD
WHEN C093 .C093_TYPE = 1 THEN NULL
WHEN C093 .C093_TYPE = 0 THEN FPC001.FPC026_COD
END AS Col1
FROM C093
LEFT JOIN FPC001 ON ... (I don't know which key you use for relation 2 tables)) AS Table_b
WHERE Table_a.C093_COD=Table_b.C093_COD
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a update-join syntax like

```
UPDATE a
SET FPC026_COD =
  CASE 
    WHEN FPC026_COD IS NOT NULL THEN FPC026_COD
    WHEN C093_TYPE = 1 THEN NULL
    WHEN C093_TYPE = 0 THEN b.FPC026_COD
  END
FROM C093 a
JOIN FPC001 b
    ON a.FPC026_COD = b.FPC026_COD;
```